# Reputation after deleting a post

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions, deleted-questions, deleted-posts

I just got started on Stack Exchange.

What happens to your reputation after deleting a question on a Stack Exchange website?

1. Do you lose the reputation associated with the deleted question?
   If yes: If you go below a privilege threshold, do you lose that privilege too?

Comment: Yes and Yes and some more text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) especially the part: **What else should I know about deleted posts?**

Comment: Hi Joris, and welcome to Meta!  A tip:  Searching [for the tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deleted-posts+discussion) will bring up helpful FAQs like the duplicate.  Or look in the help center.

Comment: Welcome to Meta Stack Exchange! Regarding this being closed as a duplicate: if a question is addressed in the answer to another "canonical" post, especially a post tagged [tag:faq], it is our policy to close it as a duplicate, so that users are pointed toward the relevant canonical answers. I understand that it may seem unfriendly, since the questions aren't the same, but those who marked your question were simply acting on that policy. See [this section of our FAQ on how Meta Stack Exchange works](/a/47635/377214) and the last section of [our FAQ on duplicate closures](/a/10844/377214).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I will check it out !